# Failed: Can't resolve all parameters for DecoratorFactory: (?)

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I'm facing the below exception when I run `ng test` for unit testing
`Failed: Can't resolve all parameters for DecoratorFactory: (?)`

Facing the exception in the below `specs.ts` file. I'm using ngx-bootstrap components in my UI

```
describe('DirectoryComponent', () => {
    let component: DirectoryComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<DirectoryComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [ DirectoryComponent ],
            imports: [ FormsModule,TypeaheadModule,BsDatepickerModule, CarouselModule, RouterTestingModule,ModalModule.forRoot() ],
            providers:[GlobalService, ServerService , OtherservicesService,MyModalsService,Pipe],
        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DirectoryComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Comment: there must be some issue with your code, post code for the relevant file.

Comment: Pls check.I have updated the question